# Are maximal compact subgroups of connected groups connected?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Assume $G$ is a connected locally compact group and $M$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. Is $M$ connected too?

Comment: Wrote something stupid - now deleted - apologies.

Comment: Me too.  To save someone else: $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not a counterexample because it is not connected!

Comment: I was very close to making the same mistake!

Comment: Well known for Lie groups, so you need something stranger.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Could you explain your comment and kindly introduce me some references?

Comment: If it is correct for Lie groups, maybe we can extend the case of Lie groups to general locally compact groups using pro-Lie groups or similar techniques.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark That was indeed the hole I feel into...

Comment: For Lie groups, the Levi-Malcev theorem says that every connected Lie group retracts to its maximal semisimple, and then it is well known that every semisimple retracts to its maximal compact. So every connected Lie group retracts to its maximal compact. This is useful in understanding the topology of a Lie group, and of its homogeneous spaces.

Comment: As a reference, look at http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1948-1951__1__271_0

Comment: @BenMcKay are you assuming G is simply connected when you use Levi-Malcev?

Comment: @YemonChoi: yes, sorry, I forgot about that. If you take quotient $G/K$ by a maximal compact, you always get a complete negative curvature metric, but you need $G$ simply connected to guarantee that $G/K$ is simply connected, and therefore contractible.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Isn't it true that $G/K$ ($K$ maximal compact) is always homeomorphic (diffeomorphic) to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$? So it should be always contractible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Locally compact groups are absolutely not my field of expertise. I hope an expert can check my statements below, and perhaps add some details and references.

The Malcev–Iwasawa theorem implies that any connected, locally compact group $G$ satisfies:

- $G$ has a maximal compact subgroup;
- there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$, the underlying space of $G$ is homeomorphic to $K\times\mathbb{R}^n$.

In particular, every maximal compact subgroup of a connected, locally compact group is itself connected.

**References:** The following references state the necessary results without proof.

- Theorem 32.5 of Markus Stroppel's book "*Locally compact groups*".
- The article "[*Compact subgroups of Lie groups and locally compact groups*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-120-02/S0002-9939-1994-1166357-9/)" (DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1994-1166357-9), published in the Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, volume 120, number 2, in February 1994 (pages 623-634). See the statements of theorems A, B, and C in the introduction to this article. According to the discussion there, the theorems hold for connected, locally compact groups: they follow from the analogous results for Lie groups as soon as one knows that a connected, locally compact group is a projective limit of Lie groups.

Comment: @BugsBunny, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140622/are-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-connected-groups-connected/140638#comment1027968_140638) question has been deleted.  Did it turn out that there is not a problem?

Comment: I think I have understood the statement in Stroppel. It was just my stupidity.

Comment: This is actually a result of Malcev: On the theory of the Lie groups in the large. Rec. Math. [Mat. Sbornik] N. S. 16(58), (1945). 163–190. This was retrieved in a 1949 paper of Iwasawa.