# Question about maximal compact subgroups of Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact (connected) semisimple Lie group. Let $G_\mathbb{C}$ be the complexification of $G$.

Is $G$ a maximal compact subgroup of $G_\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $\mathfrak g$ is a maximal subalgebra of its complexification on which the Killing form is negative definite, so at least $G$ is a maximal *connected* compact subgroup.

Comment: @LSpice maximal compact subgroups of connected Lie groups are connected (the inclusion is even a homotopy equivalence).

Comment: @LSpice For $\mathfrak{g}$ not simple, it is not true that $\mathfrak{g}$ is maximal in $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbf{C}$. For $\mathfrak{g}$ semisimple the larger subalgebras correspond to non-compact subgroups anyway, so it's fine. In the general case one should deal with the center too.

Comment: @YCor, I'm not sure what you [mean](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433874/question-about-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-lie-groups/433885#comment1117362_433874).  I did not claim that $\mathfrak g$ is maximal, only that it is maximal for the Killing form being negative definite.  Is that false?  (As to the centre, I agree that one has to worry about it, but, since $G$ is semisimple, there is not much centre.)

Comment: @LSpice ah, the formulation "maximal on which..." is ambiguous.

Comment: @YCor, ah, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433874/question-about-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-lie-groups/433885#comment1117364_433874)!  I didn't notice.  It's too late to change my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433874/question-about-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-lie-groups/433885#comment1117357_433874), but I have changed the wording in my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433885) accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Still, if the center is positive-dimensional the Killing form is not negative-definite on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @YCor, [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433874/question-about-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-lie-groups/433885#comment1117366_433874), but, if the centre is positive-dimensional, then $G_{\mathbb C}$ is not semisimple, which is assumed here.  Or am I misunderstanding?  (Anyway I guess one can pull back to $Z(G)^\circ \times G_\text{der}$ and make essentially the same argument there.)

Comment: @LSpice no, I missed the assumption (I edited to streamline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Lie{Lie}\newcommand\g{\mathfrak g}\newcommand\C{{\mathbb C}}$$\g = \Lie(G)$ is maximal among subalgebras of $\g_\C = \Lie(G_\C)$ on which the Killing form is negative definite, so $G$ is a maximal connected, compact subgroup of $G_\C$.  According to [@YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433874/question-about-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-lie-groups#comment1117360_433874), maximal compact subgroups of connected groups are connected, so $G$ is also a maximal compact subgroup.

Comment: I think this statement (that maximal compact subgroups of connected Lie groups are connected) is due to Iwasawa around 1950.

Comment: Thank you very much @LSpice and YCor for your help!

Comment: @YCor there is question about that statement here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140622/are-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-connected-groups-connected

Comment: @asma, [awesome](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433874/question-about-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-lie-groups/433885#comment1117415_433885)!  I have been [trying](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182723/conditions-that-imply-a-subgroup-normalizes-a-maximal-torus) for a long time to remember [that comment by @‍abx](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361149/does-a-compact-lie-group-have-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-of-maximal-abelian#comment910242_361151), so thank you for indirectly pointing me to it!